# Transferring ownership of an Android app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, file-transfer

So I followed all of the directions at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en&ref_topic=16285, to transfer an app from an original account to a target account, and after being notified by the support team via gmail that it successfully transferred, the Play Store page of the app still displays the original account's email address when I want it to obviously display the target account's. Is it because the APK was built and compiled in the original account?

It's a simple app (used for testing purposes), really - doesn't use integrated services or in-app billing.

How can I change the email address to the target account's? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about at the bottom of the app listing page?

```
Developer
Visit website
Email some@email.com
1234 Some Address Dr City 99999
```

1. goto your Google Play Developer console
2. goto All applications
3. Select your app
4. goto Store Listing
5. Change CONTACT DETAILS: Email

If you want to change acc-wide default, Settings > Account Details > Email address

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that... Thanks a bunch!